# php mail header allow ascii characters

Tags: php

On sending a mail I've set my header to:

```
$headers = 'From: T&#243;mas<tomas@email.com>'. "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
```

for `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

The Tómas is working in the content correctly but not in the from section of the email. It shows up like `T&#243;mas`. Any idea how to modify the header to make this work?

Many thanks.

Comment: There's no reason to encode it. Just put the character as-is right into the `From:` header.  Mail headers  don't require entity encoding like HTML markup.

Comment: In fact, since your HTML message is specified as UTF-8, you don't need to encode it as an entity in the body either. Just supply the message body as UTF-8.

Comment: When I do this though it shows up like B�thar in the from section of the email.

Comment: Sorry - you said in the From. - That's your mail client failing to display it properly. test it out a few different places and most should correctly render it.  A well behaved mail client should be able to display extended ascii in the headers.

Comment: I'm not totally correct - old RFC 2822 only permits US-ASCII, but 2047 explains how to encode the header: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047.html

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719149/send-emails-with-international-accent-and-special-characters/1719362#1719362 for an example of a base64 encoded header.

Answer (score -1):

```
T&#243;  = Tó
```

change  the following line

```
$headers = 'From: T&#243;mas<tomas@email.com>'. "\r\n";
```

with

```
$headers = 'From: Tomas<tomas@email.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: But I want the ó to show on the name Tómas. This removes it, no?