# Error sending special characters on mail function (php)

Tags: php, email

I'm using the mail function on php to send a confirmation email. It actually works, but just for some mails. For example, if you recieve that on a gmail it's fine, but on a college mail it appears ? instead of special characters. 
The problem is that that mail includes a validation link,which looks like www.myweb.com/confirmation.php?passkey=(passkey) and if the mail and the special characters aren't send properly this link is also wrong (the = doesn't appear).

I've already tried writting

```
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
```

on top of the mail function, but it doesn't work. What can it be?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check this thread for similar issue and solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719149/send-emails-with-international-accent-and-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

Try utf-8 encoding in header

For example:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. In the header there's one word with an accent and it appears, but in the rest of the body of the message there's just one ? in the middle of the word... (and the passkey code doesn't appear as it should)